# How to include the message box within the Open file dialog in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, openfiledialog

In my previous question: [How to know if the file I'm opening is a .txt file or not in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971076/how-to-know-if-the-file-im-opening-is-a-txt-file-or-not-in-vb-net)

I ask here how to know if I'm opening .txt file or not.

The code below is my code for opening a .txt file and prompt the user if the file is .txt of not.

```
Dim filename As String = String.Empty
Dim TextLine As String = ""
Dim SplitLine() As String


Dim ofd1 As New OpenFileDialog()

ofd1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
ofd1.FilterIndex = 2
ofd1.RestoreDirectory = True
ofd1.Title = "Open Text File"

'get the filename of the txt file
If ofd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
'if the file is not .txt file
        If (Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower() <> ".txt") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select text Files only", _
                            "RMI", _
                             MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                             MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

            'show the open file dialog
            ofd1.ShowDialog()

            'if the file is .txt file
        Else
            filename = ofd1.FileName
 End If

'if the filename is existing
If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) = True Then

    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

    'read the text file and populate the datagridview
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
        TextLine = TextLine.Replace(" ", "")
        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
        dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
    Loop

End If
```

If the file that I selected is not .txt file, here is the output:

[image]

If I open a file that is not existing, here is the output:

[image]

In the 1st image, it only show the error message box, but in the 2nd image, the error message box is within the open file dialog.

My question is how can I show the error message box of the 1st image with the open file dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: Check if the OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() returns OK. This means a valid file was chosen. You can use the Filter to only list .txt files - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes:

- No need to check the extension after you show the form, but you should instead set the appropriate filter in order to limit the selection of `.txt` files only  `"txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"`
- You can use the `OpenFileDialiog.CheckFileExists` and `OpenFileDialiog.CheckPathExists` properties to prevent user to enter an invalid file name/path (display an error message)
- Not sure you need to check a second time if the file exists if you use `CheckFileExists` / `CheckPathExists`
- You should always dispose a form that you show using `ShowDialog()` method.
- You should dispose the `StreamReader`

---

```
Dim filename As String = String.Empty
Dim TextLine As String = ""
Dim SplitLine() As String

Using ofd1 As New OpenFileDialog()
        ofd1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
        ofd1.FilterIndex = 2
        ofd1.CheckPathExists = True
        ofd1.CheckPathExists = True
        ofd1.RestoreDirectory = True
        ofd1.Title = "Open Text File"

        'get the filename of the txt file
        If ofd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            filename = ofd1.FileName

            Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)

                'read the text file and populate the datagridview
                Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                    TextLine = TextLine.Replace(" ", "")
                    SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
                    dvList.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
                Loop
            End Using
        End If
End Using
```

Comment: Ahh ok sir, I didn't know this before, but thanks to you now I know, and also for the added information thank you :)

Comment: Just to add to this, unfortunately this does not save you from possibly unexpected user input, setting the filter to a specified option and only allowing that filter does not restrict the file selection of the user completely, try it out `type "*" into the file name text box and hit enter, after that you will be able to select every type, regardless of the specified filter` ok what "standard" user does that, but useful to keep in mind if you want to be super safe that you get what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Here i add the label which is hidden. (name: pathlabel)
button (open file)
add openfiledialog from toolbox

this is so simple.
Open File button:

```
openfiledialog.showdialog()
```

OpenFileDialog_FileOk :

```
PathLabel.Text = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
    If PathLabel.Text = ".txt" Then
        Dim Objectreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = Objectreader.ReadToEnd
        Objectreader.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("please select only Text Document (.txt)", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End If
```

Thank you...

---

Instead of this you must set the filter to openfiledialog
button code (open file)

```
Openfiledialog.showdialog()
openfiledialog.filter = "Text Document|*.txt"
```